# Python: class methods calling other class methods when initial method is called from within another class

Tags: python, class, methods

I am working on an elaborate file switcher (in lack of a better term), and have run into a problem. Simplified, consider the code below:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = Bar()
        self.foo.baz()

class Bar(object):
    def baz(self):
        print("baz")
        self.qux()
    def qux(self):
        print("qux")
```

When the class Foo initiates, and calls "self.foo.baz()", nothing is printed in the output whatsoever. How come? Is there a way to call methods within the Bar class from within Foo properly in this case?

Comment: It works fine for me.  Note that `__init__` isn't executed until you instantiate the class.  It doesn't initialize the class, it initializes an instance.

Comment: I can't reproduce. When I call `Foo()`, both "baz" and "qux" print.

Comment: The above code, plus `Foo()` prints `baz` and `qux`. No problems there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__init__` isn't called until you create an instance.  If you create an instance:

```
a = Foo()
```

Then you should see something printed.

Comment: I hate myself a bit now for forgetting to create an instance... Thank you for the heads-up.